# Catalog rule doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2 and I made a catalog price rule with a condition, so only products that belong to some manufacturer will be discounted. I activated and applied this rule but in the front-end anything happened. The promotion should start and finish today at 23:59!
How can I view the changed prices in the front-end?

Comment: did you created manufactuer as an attribute or category? did you applied catalog price rules before? check your cron job is working or not ? did you tried reindexing once .after applying catalog price rules ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento the manufacturer is a product attribute and it's the first time that I apply a catalog price rule. The cron is working and I made the reindex after I applied the rule.

Comment: can you check the catalog prices rules are working or not by applying rules to one test category and test product.

Comment: @BabyinMagento I just applied the rule to one product, I flushed the cache and did the reindex of products price but the discount doesn't appear.

Comment: is it possible for you post a screenshot of catalog price rule you created in backend.